# How can I verify that two specific wallet addresses were involved in a transaction?

Tags: transactions, address.transfer, wallet-transfer, verify

Given I have and know WalletAddress A (sender), WalletAddress B (receiver), the Transaction Hash and the amount ETH sent. How can I verify that those values were indeed involved in the given transaction?

I checked a couple (of my own) transactions. And I know I sent some ETH from a wallet address to another wallet address. But when I check the transaction via an online explorer, the ‘sender’
 or ‘recipient’ are not always equal to my (from/to) wallet addresses.

My initial thought was to check via an online explorer the transaction by the transaction hash, and compare the ‘sender’ field and the ‘recipient’ field with WalletAddress A and WalletAddress B. But I don’t think this is a solid solution.

Summary; I want to check if a sender indeed sent a specific amount to a receiver at a specific time. But I don’t know how to approach this issue. I thought this could be accomplished when I know the transaction hash. How can I do this? And preferably with an online API and without running a (local) node.

Thank you in advance!

Edit:

This is an extreme example, but maybe the most simple one; 
I have a Coinbase account (with a 'personal' ETH address). I have a Binance account (with a 'personal' address). When I send from Coinbase to Binance, and check the transaction, I see my 'personal' *Coinbase* ETH address in the transaction, but the receiver is the 'global' Binance address. And not my 'personal' Binance address. So, I have all the values (transaction hash, to address, from address and amount), but how can I check (via an explorer) that it indeed was received at my 'personal' Binance address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed check the transaction with some online blockchain explorer if you have the transaction hash. If you doubt the results you can cross-check with different explorers.

But in general you can trust reputable online explorers so if they tell you some data it's most likely true.

If you send ETH from an address to another address get the transaction hash and check it in an online explorer it should obviously show the right results. If it shows different addresses I don't have too many ideas of what could've happened. Some ideas:

- Maybe you are mistaken in some way. Maybe your address is not what you think it is, for example?
- Maybe you use some wallet which does some extra magic under the hood, such as uses a relaying wallet or something similar.
- Maybe your wallet program is broken and shows the wrong data
- Maybe your wallet program is dishonest / compromised and it gives you different data compared to what happens in reality

Given the transaction hash you can follow the receiving address and sender address and see what other transactions they have. Maybe you can find your address somewhere along the path?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm 100% sure I sent (from WalletAddress A) and received it (in Wallet Address B). And I used online explorers with a good reputation. So maybe you are right with point 2: _'Maybe you use some wallet which does some extra magic under the hood, such as uses a relaying wallet or something similar'_. If this is the case, and I still have the above values, is it possible to check it's indeed from Wallet Address A?

Comment: Go to the transaction, go to the sender, check his transactions, check their senders etc. Follow that path until you find your address somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I will probably go with that solution. I will edit my question because I think I have a example.

Comment: Oh you are talking about transactions between exchanges. Exchange accounts are not real wallets. Exchanges utilize all sorts of magic to shuffle the assets around so you shouldn't worry if you don't see the exact addresses that you thought you'd see.

Comment: Alright, thank you @Lauri Peltonen. This clarifies things a bit more :)